# Why is KeyboardInterrupt not working for Python pyautogui script? Alternative way to exit program/loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, key-bindings, pyautogui, keyboardinterrupt

I am trying to complete a simple GUI automation program that merely opens a web page and then clicks on a specific spot on the page every 0.2 seconds until I tell it to stop. I want my code to run and have its loop run infinitely until a keybind I specify breaks the loop (or entire program). I started out with the classic KeyboardInterrupt, which supposedly enables CTRL+C to exit a program. Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser, pyautogui, time
webbrowser.open('https://example.com/')
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
time.sleep(5)
#pyautogui.moveTo(1061, 881)
try:
    while True:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            pyautogui.click(1061,881)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

Unfortunately, KeyboardInterrupt and using CTRL-C to exit do not seem to work for this script (likely due to the while loop?). This causes the loop to continue to run infinitely without a way to be stopped. So my questions are: why isn't the Keyboard Interrupt working? I've seen similar examples in other scripts. Additionally, if the KeyboardInterrupt doesn't work, is there a way I can code a simple keybind to exit the program/loop?

Comment: I suspect it may have something do to with you having a different active window than the script; when you use `webbrowser`, open a webpage, and click on it, it moves your active window to the webpage rather than the Python console. So `ctrl+c` will only produce a `KeyboardInterrupt` when the console is your active window.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think that's the case. Thank you for the response. Are there any other quick shortcuts that can quickly exit a program? I think moving the cursor into the top corner exits a script, but it's not that easy to do here.

Comment: Would you mind accepting this if I posted it as an answer? (EDIT: No, I do not no of any other quick shortcuts that can do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it may have something do to with you having a different active window than the script; when you use `webbrowser`, open a webpage, and click on it, it moves your active window to the webpage rather than the Python console. So `ctrl+c` will only produce a `KeyboardInterrupt` when the console is your active window. Your script may be in fact correct; but your active window is not on Python, so you would have to test it by clicking back into the Python console while the program runs.

To answer your comment: No, I do not know of any other "quick" way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
```

Then to stop, move the mouse to the upper-left corner of the screen

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, but I can provide a solution which allows you to press CTRL + C to stop the program. You need to install the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module and use `keyboard.is_pressed()` to catch when you press the keys you want as flag:

```
import keyboard


# You program...

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.click(1061,881)

    if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+c"):
        break
```

You need to be careful though because the program will check if you have pressed the keys only when it executes the `if` statement. If your program runs for 10 seconds and you place the `if` at the end, you will only be able to exit every 10 seconds and for a very brief moment.

I also suggest to keep the keys pressed while you wait for the program to catch them to avoid missing the moment.

If you instead need to instantly terminate the program without having to always check if CTRL+C are pressed, you can place it in a process and kill it whenever you want. It's a bit overkill and it's not the recommended way, but if you really need it, here it is.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

from multiprocessing import Process


def execute_program():
    """Long program which you want to interrupt instantly"""

    while True:
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The failsafe allows you to move the cursor on the upper left corner of the screen to terminate the program. 
    # It is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to keep it True
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

    # Spawn and start the process
    execute_program_process = Process(target=execute_program)
    execute_program_process.start()

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+c'):
            execute_program_process.terminate()
            break

    print('\nDone.')
```